# Django-orm. Как откатить изменения в бд, если произошла ошибка во время выполнения кода? Транзакции?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

То есть например исполняется себе код, который должен изменить несколько **разных** моделей. Обязательно это **разные** модели. Например пять.

Предположим, что две модели он изменил, и выскочило исключение. Соответственно три модели остались недоделанными.

Как возможно откатить изменения в первых двух моделях, чтобы сохранить целостность вычислений?

Из всех способов, я пока вижу только джанговские транзакции. Но транзакции, насколько я помню, посылают много запросов к бд, чтобы никто другой не мог за это время внести изменения.

Или в джанге транзакции по другому работают? В доке написано, что они замедляют работу программы, и желательно оборачивать в транзакции как можно меньшие участки.

Как лучше поступить? Может есть возможность отката с помощью питоновских исключений?

> Немного поразбирал эту тему. Сделал некоторые выводы. Выяснил, что в sqlalchemy, вообщем-то используется этот же механизм, просто в джанго, в отличие от sqlalchemy, изначально включен автокоммит. Сам же уровень изолированности транзакций, настраивается в самой бд. Вообщем-то использовать транзакции с помощью джанго, это самый верный вариант. Да и, наименее затратный по времени. Просто надо их внедрять изначально, в стиль кодирования. Тогда толк будет хороший. И использоваться они будут наиболее оптимально.

Comment: а не легче ли сначала обработать данные, а потом их одним запросом сохранить в БД?

Comment: @Komdosh, джанговский орм же. Там нельзя так. Ща проправлю название. Тег наверное не заметен.

Comment: Во-первых, транзакции не джанговские, а базы данных. Во-вторых, работают они не так. В некоторых случаях они даже ускоряют работу. В-третьих, в Django ORM можно обработать данные и сохранить одним запросом. Наконец, оптимизацией стоит озадачиться тогда, когда производительность вашего ресурса опустится ниже позволительного значения и проблема будет в блокировках данных транзакциями. Make it Work, Make it Right, Make it Fast.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, _Наконец, оптимизацией стоит озадачиться тогда, когда производительность вашего ресурса опустится ниже позволительного значения и проблема будет в блокировках данных транзакциями._ Я не считаю что тут речь идёт о преждевременной оптимизации. С вашей позиции дак хоть целый запрос в транзакцию оборачивай. Тут скорее о стиле написания кода речь идёт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый правильный и, пожалуй, единственный в Django способ - это завернуть все взаимозависимые изменения в БД в одну транзакцию:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    first_model = FirstModel()
    first_model.save()
    second_model = SecondModel.objects.last()
    second_model.some_filed = 'Some value'
    second_model.save()
```

Естественно, следует стараться сократить время нахождения в транзакции. Если стоит выбор между тем, чтобы пометить объёмный метод декоратором `@atomic` и выполнить только часть кода в контексте менеджера `atomic`, выбирайте второе.

Django - монолитный фреймворк, позволяющий описывать бизнес-логику в стиле очень близком к декларативному. Это, в свою очередь, позволяет экономить самый дорогой ресурс - время и силы программиста. Но только до тех пор, пока вы решаете типовые задачи. Если нужно реализовать что-то необычное или максимально эффективно утилизировать мощности, фреймворк не только перестанет помогать, он начнёт работать против вас.

Необходимость тонкого управления транзакциями для соблюдения ACID в длительно выполняющемся коде без того, чтобы ставить всю базу колом - это как раз тот случай, когда вы потратите больше сил на обход правил фреймворка, чем на реализацию этой задачи с нуля другим способом, без ORM или вообще к Django не относящимся.

Comment: Это вы обернули изменения в транзакцию. Да это вариант, пока единственный который я вижу. Оправдан ли он?

Comment: Абсолютно оправдан.

Comment: А если вычисления в сумме, например, полсекунды? И они оборачиваются в транзакцию?

Comment: В таком случае первым делом стоит заняться оптимизацией этих вычислений. Если не выйдет, изменением логики так, чтобы вычисления можно было делать не в транзакции. Если и это не выйдет, останется только отказываться от ORM, работать с базой запросами, явно управлять блокировками в транзакциях и, возможно, выносить тяжёлую логику в хранимые процедуры.

Comment: вы просто выложили код с использование транзакции в django. Не могли бы вы раскрыть свой ответ, или как-то обосновать?

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, на определённом уровне абстракции, уже не контролируешь, то что происходит внутри. Надо ли оборачивать всю абстракцию, или углубляться в код, чтобы обернуть нужные места, например? Или надо сразу выносить сохранения в отдельные места, и оборачивать их там? Вообщем, что оправдано, непонятно.

Comment: Немного поразбирал эту тему. Сделал некоторые выводы. Выяснил, что в sqlalchemy, вообщем-то используется этот же механизм. Просто в джанго изначально включен автокоммит. А уже уровень изолированности транзакций, настраивается в самой бд. Вообщем-то использовать транзакции с помощью джанго, это самый верный вариант. Да и, как вы сказали, наименее затратный по времени. Просто надо их внедрять изначально, в стиль кодирования. Тогда толк будет хороший.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить о долгих вычислениях, то обычная практика разбивать транзакцию на две. Для этого вам нужно какое-то поле статуса у объекта.

1. В первой транзакции вы находите все объекты для работы с подходящим статусом ("В очереди") и меняете статус на другой ("В работе"). Транзакцию закрываете.
2. По завершении работы открываете ещё одну транзакцию и переносите объекты в следующий статус ("Готово") с сохранением результатов работы.

Вторая транзакция может быть не нужна. Смотрите по обстоятельствам.

Этот подход не без недостатков:

- Важно чтобы весь остальной код учитывал статус и не прикасался к объектам со статусом "В работе" или аналогичным. Это может быть сложно сделать.
- Если в процессе обработки объекта произойдёт какой-нибудь фатальный сбой (например, закончится память), то задача окажется в подвешенном состоянии. Нужно будет изобретать способ искать такие задачи, которые не менялись больше какого-то времени, возвращать их в предыдущий статус и т.п.

Можно придумать и другие способы сократить возможные задержки из-за транзакций. Например, используя запросы вида `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` или ещё как. Это всё не обязательно можно просто сделать с ORM.

#### Итого

Если вы делаете очередь задач, то используйте специально предназначенные для этого механизмы (Redis, RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ...) и продуманные библиотеки (Celery, Resque...), которые уже учитывают все возможные проблемные места.

Comment: А если в процессе работы произойдёт сбой, то все объекты так и зависнут навсегда в статусе "в работе".

Comment: Ещё веселее становится ситуация, если обработка требует промежуточных изменений в БД, в случае ошибки база перейдёт в несогласованное состояние.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вы всё верно говорите; дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Очень интересный вариант.